# Is there a supported yet undocumented way to define input size on different view ports

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4's [input group sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#sizing) but I am using it within [ReactStrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/input-group/) library.

I can defined input sizes in core bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Large</span>
 </div>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Large" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
</div>
```

and in reactstrap like this:

```
<div>
  <InputGroup size="lg">
    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">@lg</InputGroupAddon>
    <Input />
  </InputGroup>
</div>
```

Is there away to change the size alongside the css for media check? Like the way `col-md-12` so that we can have a large input on medium size screen(e.g `input-group-md-lg`) or small input on xtra small devices(e.g `input-group-xm-sm`)?